# need to split Packet for each Instance and for each InstanceData

Tags: c#

I have below classes,

```
public class Packet
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public Result Results { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public string ResultName { get; set; }
        public List<Instance> Instances { get; set; }
    }

    public class Instance
    {
        public string InstanceName { get; set; }
        public List<InstanceData> InstanceDatas { get; set; }
    }

    public class InstanceData
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Now, I have data coming from one service like this C# object,

```
var dataPacket = new Packet
        {
            Id = new Guid("2e08bd98-68eb-4358-8efb-9f2adedfb034"),
            Results = new Result
            {
                ResultName = "ResultName1",
                Instances = new List<Instance>
                {
                    new Instance
                    {
                        InstanceName = "InstanceName1",
                        InstanceDatas = new List<InstanceData>
                        {
                            new InstanceData{Name = "N1", Value = "V1"},
                            new InstanceData{Name = "N2", Value = "V2"}
                        }
                    },
                    new Instance
                    {
                        InstanceName = "InstanceName2",
                        InstanceDatas = new List<InstanceData>
                        {
                            new InstanceData{Name = "N1", Value = "V1"}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

In one `Packet`, We have one or more `Instance` and each `Instance` we have one or more `InstanceData`. I need to split out this and I want multiple `Packet`. **Each `Packet` should have only one `Instance` and only one `InstanceData`**. Example.

```
var dataPacket1 = new Packet
        {
            Id = new Guid("2e08bd98-68eb-4358-8efb-9f2adedfb034"),
            Results = new Result
            {
                ResultName = "ResultName1",
                Instances = new List<Instance>
                {
                    new Instance
                    {
                        InstanceName = "InstanceName1",
                        InstanceDatas = new List<InstanceData>
                        {
                            new InstanceData{Name = "N1", Value = "V1"},
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        var dataPacket2 = new Packet
        {
            Id = new Guid("2e08bd98-68eb-4358-8efb-9f2adedfb034"),
            Results = new Result
            {
                ResultName = "ResultName1",
                Instances = new List<Instance>
                {
                    new Instance
                    {
                        InstanceName = "InstanceName1",
                        InstanceDatas = new List<InstanceData>
                        {
                            new InstanceData{Name = "N2", Value = "V2"},
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

I tried to loop first on `Instances` and then on `InstanceDatas`, but not sure how to make packet? Please suggest. Thanks!

```
var packet = new Packet();

        foreach (var instance in dataPacket.Results.Instances)
        {
            foreach (var data in instance.InstanceDatas)
            {
                packet.Id = new Guid("2e08bd98-68eb-4358-8efb-9f2adedfb034");
                packet.Results.ResultName = "ResultName1";
                packet.Results.Instances[0].InstanceName = instance.InstanceName;
                packet.Results.Instances[0].InstanceDatas[0].Name = data.Name;
                packet.Results.Instances[0].InstanceDatas[0].Value = data.Value;
            }
        }
```

Comment: The data is binary so you need to add a header when sending the data that include the number of bytes.  Then when you receive the data read the byte count to determine where the data ends.

Comment: which data is binary? I need to spit

Comment: If you are sending the serialized classes than it is binary.  You could be converting to a base64 string.  Then you can either add a character that is not part of the base 64 string to spit data or add a byte count to use for splitting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question, you can use `Select` and `SelectMany`

```
var packets = dataPacket.Results
   .Instances
   .SelectMany(x =>
      x.InstanceDatas.Select(y => new Packet()
      {
         Id = dataPacket.Id,
         Results = new Result()
         {
            ResultName = dataPacket.Results.ResultName,
            Instances = new List<Instance>()
            {
               new Instance()
               {
                  InstanceDatas = new List<InstanceData>() {y},
                  InstanceName = x.InstanceName
               }
            }
         }
      }));
```

Comment: Thanks, but `Packet` Id is null rather than ""2e08bd98-68eb-4358-8efb-9f2adedfb034"

Comment: `Packet` Id = {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}, it should be "2e08bd98-68eb-4358-8efb-9f2adedfb034"

Comment: Ok, nvm. I added `Id = dataPacket.Id,`

Comment: This doesn't help in splitting the data.  How can you tell where each packet ends.

Comment: @jdweng yeah i see where you are going with that line of questioning, but i read the question as just a poco class problem, not over-the-wire serialization issue. but i could be wrong

Comment: The OP said following : "Now, I have data coming from one service like this C# object," and is using PACKET.  The problem is data can be split into multiple packets and if you do no wait until all the data is received before processing you will get an exception.

Comment: @jdweng, sorry for the confusion. The data already I have in C# object completely after receiving from service, I don't have anything partial.

Comment: Then why do you need to split?  What is the criteria for splitting?